# update mysql detabase by using ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

how we can update mysql detabase by using ajax...

any help or consept..

Comment: Please edit your question; adding the following points may get you better answers: 1. What are you trying to accomplish (update for *what* purpose?)? 2. What have you tried so far? 3. What results did you get? 4. How did that differ from the results you were expecting?

Comment: i want to update session out time on keypress event..

Comment: on key press event i call a function-------and the function body is  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ajaxupdate.php",
 });

Comment: ajaxupdate.php---body---<?php 
session_start();
include ('../common.php');
mysql_query("UPDATE set_time SET logout_time = '86409' WHERE id =1");
?>

Comment: please post all your associated code (edit your question context) - this way we can help you

Answer (score 1):

Ajax will have to call a remote script which will have to take care of the databse interaction.  The code depends on the script language your database handling script will be written in.

You may have a look [here for an example of ajax and mysql interaction](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajax-mysql-database.php).

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a url from javascript, and do the job serverside.

Answer (score 0):

1. We **cannot** update mysql database by using ajax!
2. Thus, divide your task into 2 parts:

   - make ordinal php script that updates a database by usual POST request.
     debug it and make it to work
   - make AXAX code to make such a request.
     debug it and make it to work

this way you can get your application working